# What are the rules of town-living in "The Land of The Lost"?

Tags: jk-rowling, the-christmas-pig

In JK Rowling's The Christmas Pig, the "things" live in a series of towns depending on how much they're loved and missed, following a complex system of rules.

What are the rules? What are the requirements of being missed or loved in order to live in a certain town?